# Is it possible? Python send Hex code via usb port (raspberry pi)

Tags: c#, python, hex, usb, raspberry-pi3

Hi every one but first let me say sorry about my english. I hope you guys will understand what I mean :)

---

> Question :

Is it possible that RaspberryPi with RASPBIAN OS can communicates with PZEM-004T Energy monitor via USB port. I want to use Python to send Hexadecimal Code to request such as voltage, current, power and energy then read data that reply from module(PZEM-004T) and keep it into phpMyadmin.

---

> For example

---

If I send hex command code : B1 C0 A8 01 01 00 1B, 
module will replys data back : A1 00 11 20 00 00 D2.
Then convert replied data to decimal and keep it into database.

please suggest me what is the best way to success this challenge :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible with a library such as `pyserial`. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570526/sending-hex-over-serial-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using libraries such as `pyserial` like Leon said for the serial communication.

For the SQL database, you can use `sqlalchemy` to manage it.

This module (PZEM-004T) uses TTL serial communication, so if yours is not selled with an USB adapter you need one like a FTDI232 based one for example.

I don't know what your program is intended for, but as it's a datalogger, if you want it to run every time your raspberry pi reboot you can call it in your `/etc/rc.local`