# How do I convert a list of ASCII "Bytes" in Python into Hex Bytes

Tags: python, hex, ascii, pyserial

I have a list of ASCII "bytes", that I need to convert to hex, and then send over a serial port.

For example, take the following list:

```
list_to_send=['FE','FE','98','E0''07', 'D2', '00','FD"]
```

I'd like to convert each byte to hex so that for example the first byte would look like this:

```
b'\xfe'
```

I've tried using binascii, but I think my usage is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using join()

```
str="b'"
for x in list_to_send:
    str=str+"\x"+x
str=str+"'"
```

[Sending hex over serial with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570526/sending-hex-over-serial-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Python 3.5 and above,then use this

```
b'\xFE'.hex()
```

And if you wanna use binascii ,then :

```
import binascii
binascii.hexlify('FE'.encode('utf8'))
```

there are many other ways too...
for more info 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/510399-byte-to-hex-and-hex-to-byte-string-conversion/

Comment: I'm a bit confused. {b'\xFE'} would be my desired output, not the input.